# Shell 'tar: not found in archive' error when using regular expression

Tags: linux, shell, tar

When I use `tar -xzf *.gz` to extract all the `.gz` files in the current directory, I get `Not found in archive` error. However, it works fine if I extract one by one or use a for-loop like

```
for file in `ls *.gz`; do tar -xzf $file; done
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: it is caused by the fact that argument syntax of tar accept just one single tar in the command line and the rest is interpreted as something else. You could use xargs also (`ls *.gz |xargs -n1 tar -xzf` or alike).

Comment: tar do not accept glob pattern as argument (i.e. it won't interpret it) afaik

Comment: @ShinTakezou: but the shell will expand the `*.gz` notation; `tar` won't (usually) see the `*.gz`.  Sometimes, you want to extract files with the `*` in the name.  For example: `tar -xf abc.tar.gz 'src/prog/*name.*'` would extract files such as `src/prog/bigname.c`, `src/prog/smallname.h`; the single quotes prevent the shell from expanding the `*` and `tar` does indeed expand it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know that ofcourse.In fact,I wrote `tar accepts just one single tar in the command line`,i.e. I imagined the OP thought `tar -xzf *.gz` would work as other cmds accepting more file to work on,but tar interprets `the rest` as something else,i.e. `tar -xzf 1.gz 2.gz 3.gz` would consider only 1.gz as "tar".I missed to specify the expansion of the shell,but it is clear I assumed it.The second comment answered to a now deleted comment saying to escape the `*` (to avoid shell expansion).So I noted that to tar `*.gz` is not a glob pattern,unless it'd interpret it,and afaik it won't

Comment: I'm addressing your second comment: _tar do not accept glob pattern as argument (i.e. it won't interpret it) afaik_.  AFAICS, that says that you cannot do what I show should work; `tar` _does_ expand glob patterns if requested/required to do so.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you write:

```
tar -xf *.gz
```

the `tar` command sees (for example):

```
tar -xf abc.tar.gz def.tar.gz ghi.tar.gz
```

This is interpreted as a request to extract `def.tar.gz` and `ghi.tar.gz` from the archive `abc.tar.gz`.  Since the files aren't in there, you get the warning message.

In other words, `tar` operates on a single `tar` file (possibly compressed) at a time (in one invocation).  It does not operate on multiple tar files.

Note that if `abc.tar.gz` contains a file `pqr/xyz/important.c`, you can extract just the one file by specifying:

```
tar -xf abc.tar.gz pqr/xyz/important.c
```

The notation you used is only a variant on this notation.

(And yes, there can be reasons to `tar` a `tar` file.  For example, Gmail does not allow you to ship a tar file or a gzipped tar file which contains a file that is executable.  However, if you embed a gzipped tar file inside a non-compressed tar file, it does not look inside the inner file to find the executable file.  I use this when I need to ship a tar file with an executable `configure` script.)

Answer (score 75):

When you write

```
 tar -xzf *.gz
```

your shell expands it to the string:

```
 tar -xzf 1.gz 2.gz 3.gz
```

(assuming 1.gz, 2.gz and 3.gz are in you current directory).

`tar` thinks that you want to extract `2.gz` and `3.gz` from `1.gz`; it can't find these files in the archives and that causes the error message.

You need to use loop `for` of command `xargs` to extract your files.

```
ls *.gz |xargs -n1 tar -xzf
```

That means: run me `tar -xzf` for every `gz`-file in the current directory.

Answer (score 5):

the main reason is `tar` takes a single filename argument. When you are calling `tar *.tgz` bash extends the `*` to all file names with tgz formant and it becomes `tar file1 file2 file3` which is not accepted by `tar`. So either you use a for loop like `for i in *.tgz; do tar -zxvf $i ;done` or use some other command which executes `tar` as a side effect like shown in comments, is `ls` or `find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*tgz -exec tar -zxvf {} \;` (`ls` output is always risky)

Comment: Why ls output is always risky?

Comment: The output from `ls` is ambiguous if the names contain white space or newlines.  With names without white space (including no newlines), it is fine, but you can't rely on names without space these days.

Comment: ```for i in *.tgz; do tar -zxvf "$i" ;done``` would work better.